# How to split received data into classes based on content

Tags: python

I am trying to write a chunk of code that will organize different types of data into classes. I can split them as of now, but I'm not sure how to get Python to look at the string and automatically sort them into either class based on the content of the string. For example, I have the following and would like to pass the string to either class depending on which type of data is being given to me:

```
#The data comes in by two different types continuously and is displayed as such below:

animal=dog, age=13, colour=brown, name=Jeff
animal=cat, age=9, colour=white, declawed=yes, friendly=yes, name=Jimmy


class Dogclass():
    def __init__(self,age,colour,name):
        self.age = age
        self.colour = colour
        self.name = name


class Catclass():
    def __init__(self,age,colour,declawed,friendly,name):
        self.age = age
        self.colour = colour
        self.declawed = declawed
        self.friendly = friendly
        self.name = name


def splitter():
    m = re.split('[, =]', data),
    if "dog" in m:
```

I would like my splitter function to not only have the ability to split the strings, but also go on to sort the split data into classes. This is what I had before (did not work) but would like to figure out a way to utilize OOP more and understand the use of classes.

```
dog = []
cat = []

def splitter(data):
    m = re.split('[, =]', data)
    if 'dog' in m:
        dog['age'] = (m[7])
        dog['colour'] = (m[11])
        dog['name'] = (m[13])
    elif 'cat' in m:
        cat['age'] = (m[7])
        cat['colour'] = (m[9])
        cat['declawed'] = (m[11])
        cat['friendly'] = (m[13])
        cat['name'] = (m[15])
    else:
        return()
```

I have also tried to create dictionaries to store the data I want to call to, but everything I have tried does not successfully take the splitted data and assign it to a value within my dictionary. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have an access to the data that come into your program (is it from a Java program for example ? i say that because the toString method of a java object will give you this type of notation...)

Comment: another question is : does your data will always come as you wrote ? animals=dog for example

Comment: @yAzou the data that comes in is not through java, so unfortunately I wouldn't be able to take advantage of that. The data always comes in in the same format that I posted above, I just simplified it in an attempt to make it a bit easier to digest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you got a string that represent data like this :

```
"animal=dog, age=13, colour=brown, name=Jeff"
```

The fisrt thing you would have to do is to parse it to a dictionary like object with a simple function like this one :

```
def parser(stringToParse):
    remove_space = stringToParse.replace(" ", "")
    addQuotes = {i.split('=')[0]: i.split('=')[1]
             for i in remove_space.split(',')}
    return addQuotes
```

Then you would get an object and you could get its corresponding class by any of the corresponding attribute (lets say your class is based on the "animal" attribute, you could define a simple function to to that :

```
def getConstructor(classname):
    return globals()[classname]
```

All in one :

```
import json


class dog():
    def __init__(self, age, colour, name):
        self.age = age
        self.colour = colour
        self.name = name


class cat():
    def __init__(self, age, colour, declawed, friendly, name):
        self.age = age
        self.colour = colour
        self.declawed = declawed
        self.friendly = friendly
        self.name = name


def parser(stringToParse):
    remove_space = stringToParse.replace(" ", "")
    addQuotes = {i.split('=')[0]: i.split('=')[1]
                 for i in remove_space.split(',')}
    return addQuotes


def getConstructor(classname):
    return globals()[classname]


def buildIt(any_animal):
    my_animal = parser(any_animal)
    my_animal_constructor = getConstructor(my_animal["animal"])
    if my_animal_constructor.__name__ == "dog":
        return dog(my_animal["age"], my_animal["colour"], my_animal["name"])


my_new_animal = buildIt("animal=dog, age=13, colour=brown, name=Jeff")
print(my_new_animal.colour)
```

In this example i build a dog from the input. If you try to print its coulour you get : "brown"

Of course you will have to implement the if statement for the other class in order to get the cat (and other) class work too...

***EDIT***
Also, if you want to improve your code you should implement it as an Object oriented one as suggested in Yaron Grushka's answer (create an Animal parent class and makes cat and dog inherit from it)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very helpful. I think my original question may have been unclear - my goal for the code is to split the data (which I am currently able to do) and then take the split data, look for a specific string within the split (in this example, 'dog' and 'cat' are supposed to be the differentiators) and then put the relevant data that goes along with dog/cat into their own respective classes. Maybe I am improperly using classes, but I just want the updated data that I am receiving to be separated based on the type of data (cat/dog data) and be stored with the rest of the string.

Comment: Extra clarification - I would like Python to:
- look at the data received
- find either cat/dog key words
- store the associated data by their respective key words

Cat and dog data have different strings associated with them, so I'm not sure that inheritance would be completely applicable here. The data I am receiving do not share any parameters beyond the type (cat/dog)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest that in general for cases like these that you use inheritance. You can have a parent class called `Animal` which has all the common attributes such as age, name and color. Then you can create the `Cat` and `Dog` classes that inherit from the parent class, each having unique attributes (such as declawed for cats). Like so:

```
class Animal():
    def __init__(self, name, age, colour):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.colour = colour

class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name, age, colour, declawed, friendly):
        super().__init__(name, age, colour)
        self.declawed = declawed # Can make this a boolean with an if/else
        self.friendly = friendly # Same
```

For splitting, you can actually use the `split` function that Python offers, and use commas as the separator. Then make it into a dictionary. e.g:

```
def create_animal(data):
    details = data.split(",");
    attributes = {}
    for detail in details:
        pair = detail.split("=")
        attributes[pair[0]] = pair[1]
    print(attributes)

    if attributes["animal"] == "cat":
        animal = Cat(attributes[" name"], attributes[" age"], attributes[" colour"], attributes[" declawed"], attributes[" friendly"])

    else: # Dog creation, same idea...

    return animal


a = create_animal("animal=cat, age=9, colour=white, declawed=yes, friendly=yes, name=Jimmy")
print(a.name)
# =>"Jimmy"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very helpful. I think my original question may have been unclear - my goal for the code is to split the data (which I am currently able to do) and then take the split data, look for a specific string within the split (in this example, 'dog' and 'cat' are supposed to be the differentiators) and then put the relevant data that goes along with dog/cat into their own respective classes. Maybe I am improperly using classes, but I just want the updated data that I am receiving to be separated based on the type of data (cat/dog data) and be stored with the rest of the string.

Comment: If splitting the data into 2 disjoint sets before working on creating class instances is crucial, you can always: 1. create 2 lists (like you already did). 2. split the strings of data into the 2 lists using a regular expression (e.g anything with `"=cat"` goes to the cat list and anything with `"=dog"` goes to the dog list). 3. iterate over the two lists and apply the creation of class instances - the implementation that I wrote above should work well for you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I thought that the list way would be the easiest way to do it, but I think that I have the execution wrong. When I run my code after splitting the data, it still does not save to my dictionary and I cannot access the data that I want. Are there any recommendations you can make so that the list part of the code that I posted above actually works? Thanks a tonne!

Comment: @fibbz That's probably because you define lists with `dog = []`, `cat = []`. But you then try putting values in them as you would in a dictionary (e.g `dog['age'] = (m[7])`). You can create dictionaries instead of lists in the first place (e,g  `dog = {}`, `cat = {}`, note the curly braces instead of square brackets).

Comment: I tried to do that and do the same with a dictionary, but I still have not had any luck. Correct me if I am wrong, but I am attempting to do something like this: dog = { 'age' : [], } and then assigning the split value to that by going dog['age'] = (m[7]) but still no avail. ((side note - (m[7]) is the value from the split that i want to insert into the [age] parameter)) Thanks again!